# Using jQuery basic functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with call any jQuery function.

The load is working, but when I call another page nothing is working?

my code is:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load('page.php');

    $("#submenu").click(function () {
       alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

page.php

```
<div id="submenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#profile">profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#logout">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you including the jquery.js library on all of your pages? Can you show the html/js for a page that isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "when I call another page", but if you're trying to setup event handlers for elements within the content being loaded you need to wait until they have loaded - the [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous, which means the code after it is executed immediately (i.e., without waiting for a response to the load) so to assign your `.click()` handler once it has completed move that part of your code into the `.load()` method's complete callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load('page.php', function() {
       $("#submenu").click(function () {
          alert('Hello');
       });
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can use delegated event handling and bind the click handler to your container object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").load('page.php');

    $("#content").delegate("#submenu", "click", function () {
       alert('Hello');
    });
});
```

See the [`.delegate()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for more information, and note that if you are using the latest version of jQuery you should use the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than `.delegate()`. (Or if you have a really old version of jQuery you'll need to use `.live()`.)